# Http caching - style.css?123 or style_123.css?

Tags: http, caching

I'm currently playing around with a build / deployment script for minifying static resources. Following good practice I'd like to set an expire header far into the future for most of my javascript, stylesheet and images.

To my question, when one or more of the static files has changed clients should ask for the newest version of the file. Will adding something like /css/style.css **?1235** after the url be enough to trigger a new request? Or do I have to rename all my static files for each build (something like /css/style **_12345**.css)?

Update: Just to clarify, the reason that I'm asking is that I've noticed that a lot of other deployment scripts seems to take the "hard" path by renaming each file.

Comment: The advantage of the *hard* way is that you can very simply keep all older versions available, which can be useful if you want to use a particular version of say an API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RFC 2616 [3.2 Uniform Resource Identifiers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.2) says:

> As far as HTTP is concerned, Uniform Resource Identifiers are simply formatted strings which identify--via name, location, or any other characteristic--a resource.

So, `http://foo/bar` is a different resource to `http://foo/bar?baz`.

Some URIs are treated as equivalent, so `http://foo/bar?baz` is the same resource as `http://foo/bar?BAZ` (see [3.2.3 URI Comparison](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.2.3)).

HTTP does contain some caching exceptions for handling the [query part](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) (see [13.9 Side Effects of GET and HEAD](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13.9)). I understand these to only apply to the exact same query.

Answer (score 3):

> Will adding something like
>   /css/style.css ?1235 after the url be
>   enough to trigger a new request?

Yes, of course.

You can do it like this:

`style.css?UNIXTIMESTAMP`

where UNIXTIMESTAMP is the time when the file was created in unix timestamp format

Comment: I'm probably going to use the revision number from my vcs.

Comment: Just remember that "/css/style.css" is different than "/css/style.css?12345" inside of the browser cache. What that means is that if pages A and B both link to the former, if you update page A with the latter, page B will still point to the former. Then if you change page B to be "/css/style.css?6789" you'll have a third copy in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use mod_rewrite i add a rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/((.*)_[0-9]+(\.(?:js|css|swf).*))$ /$2$3 [NC,L]
```

which rewrites any javascript, css or flash file back to the original name so

```
/css/style_1234.css
```

gets rewritten back to

```
/css/style.css
```

Comment: Overkill!!!!!!! There is no need to do it in this way!! All you need to do is that what I wrote in my answer. Nothing more. Simple add `?something` after the name of the file.

Comment: for a large dynamic site you can program the "_number" to follow a version number and so update a number of files at the same time to the latest version without worrying about caching issues.

Comment: You are right, I've forgot about caching issues. Anyway, as you said, it can be best solution for "a large dynamic site".

Comment: @Balon Overkill, but perfectly acceptable, and it'll work just fine.